# How to optimize MariaDB database when it is serving queries

Tags: mariadb

We would like to run an optimization on our MariaDB database while still allowing it to serve queries.

I see that for MySQL this is possible since 5.7.4 (from [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html))

> For InnoDB tables prior to 5.7.4 and other table types, MySQL locks
>   the table during the time OPTIMIZE TABLE is running. As of MySQL
>   5.7.4, OPTIMIZE TABLE is performed online for regular and partitioned InnoDB tables.

Does anyone know how we can do it for MariaDB as well? I see no mention at the [MariaDB OPTIMIZE page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/optimize-table/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Do you want to optimize MariaDB tables or do you want to run OPTIMIZE TABLE on MariaDB?* Because those are 2 things that have nothing to do with each other.

**Optimizing**, in general, is not a process as easy as running a command- you need to analyze your server, profile your queries, change your schema, check your configuration; select, dimension and configure your hardware and os correctly, and use it efficiently from your application.

**OPTIMIZE TABLE** is a command that -to summarize-, for MyISAM and InnoDB MySQL/MariaDB engines, it defragments your table- in most cases with no real impact on performance, although it can save space under certain circunstances. Please do not execute optimize table regularly, [it serves no purpose in most cases](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2010/02/07/how-often-should-you-use-optimize-table/), while creating a lot of work for the servers (it basically recreates the table).

Online alter table is only possible on MySQL >=5.6+, and equivalent versions of MariaDB. `OPTIMIZE TABLE` basically runs `ALTER TABLE <table> ENGINE=InnoDB` for InnoDB tables, which is known to be able to be [online since 5.6.17 for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html). I cannot say for sure for MariaDB 10+, as it will depend on the exact version, but that is as easy to check as forcing it to be online with the `LOCK=NONE` parameter, which would fail immediately otherwise.

If for any reason you cannot run a table defragmentation online, you can always use [pt-online-schema](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html) change and perform a null operation, which will copy the new table without (almost) any locking.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I meant `OPTIMIZE TABLE`

Answer (score 1):

Not yet documented but

```
ALTER TABLE t ENGINE=InnoDB, ALGORITHM=INPLACE;
```

Is definitively working

(There is also an open bug on the topic here https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10453)